# Probability letters

Tags: probability, statistics

I've recently gone back to my old math textbook, and this question stumped me...

8 letters: KNKVVGA, I draw 2 right away. What's the probability of getting an A and N?

Probably easy for the lot of you, but I'm dumbfounded. Thanks!

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, never mind. I realized where I went wrong. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are eight letters, so the total number of two-letter combinations is ${8\choose2}=28$. There are four combinations that give you one A and one K (there are two A's and two K's), so since each two-letter combination is equally likely we have that the probability of getting one A and one K is $\frac4{28}=\frac17$.

Answer (score 3):

Think about it step by step. What's the probability you draw an A *THEN* a K?

Well there are two As out of eight letters, so the probability you pick an A is 2/8 = 1/4. There are now seven letters remaining, two of which are Ks. The probability you pick one of these Ks is then 2/7.

But then you have the event that you picked a K first then an A. But this is exactly the same probability as above, so we just multiply by two in our calculation.

So our probability is $\frac{1}{4} * \frac{2}{7} * 2 = \frac{1}{7}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Probability}=\frac{\text{Favourable Outcomes}}{\text{Total Outcomes}}=\frac{\rm |\{(A_1,K_1),(A_2,K_2),(A_2,K_1),(A_1,K_2)\}|}{{}^8{\mathbb C}_2}=\frac{1}{7}$$